# Java : Getting NullPointerException while parsing the List and setting it inside a Array

Tags: java

This is my Java program , where i am setting the Objects with in the for loop as shown

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for(int j = 0;j<=4;j++)
{
Student student = new Student();
studunt.name="Ravi";
list.add(student);
}
```

**Then i need to  parse this List and set it inside a StudentResponse ( Which is consisting of a Student[])**

```
StudentResponse  response = new StudentResponse();

    for (int in = 0; in < list.size(); in++) {
    {
    Student data = (TopListsQuoteData) list.get(in);
    response. student[in] = data;
    }
```

**This is my  StudentResponse  class**

```
public class StudentResponse 
{
public  Student[] student;
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException at this line 
response. student[in] = data;

Please help , Thanks .

Comment: How is your `public  Student[] student;`  variable initialized ?

Comment: It is also helpful if the code you post is at least compilable. You declare a variable named `student` then work with another variable named `studunt`. What other differences might there be between what you have and what we see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array before you can use it. Something like this:

```
StudentResponse  response = new StudentResponse();
response.student = new Student[list.size()];
for (int in = 0; in < list.size(); in++) {
{
    Student data = (TopListsQuoteData) list.get(in);
    response. student[in] = data;
}
```

Also i would suggest to use the iterator of the list instead of accessing the items by index. This works, but I feel it's not so clean and definitely not as efficient.

Comment: You would still need to maintain an index to address the resultant student[] array, so using foreach in this context is probably not that  much cleaner - also, you claim it's less efficient to index the list by in - generally, List.get() is O(1).

Answer (score 6):

### Initialize!

like

```
public  Student[] student = new Student[100];
```

may be.

or

```
public StudentResponse(int capacity){
   this.student = new Student[capacity];
}
```

Comment: That would still contain nulls. Olivier Roger's comment is the key point.

Comment: well, as far as you see the code, this operation `response. student[in] = data;` is throwing exception. Unless you're explicitly setting response.student null elsewhere, this code would work. Obviously, the array will contain null, so, if you pull an element that was not set to anything will see a null. But insertion will go fine as long you're not crossing the bound of the array. I guess this is the whole point here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you initialise your array in the constructor of `StudentResponse`? Something like

```
public StudentResponse(int numberOfStudents) {
   this.student = new Student[numberOfStudents];
}
```

You may want to switch out the student array as another kind of list - lists are generally much nicer to work with.

```
public class StudentResponse {
    private List<Student> students;

   public StudentResponse() {
      this.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
   }

   public void addStudent(Student student) {
       this.students.add(student);
   }

   public List<Student> getStudents() {
       return this.students;
   }

}
```

Now you can modify your code like so:

```
StudentResponse  response = new StudentResponse();

for (int in = 0; in < list.size(); in++) {
{
Student data = (TopListsQuoteData) list.get(in);
response.addStudent(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And you have a spelling Error in your code

```
Student student = new Student();
studunt.name="Ravi";
```

but I think you want:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.name="Ravi";
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a copy of the list, but as an array:

```
response.student = list.toArray(new Student[list.size()]);
```